# android Intents inline-data size limit

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I have found that the android stock camera app, when passing an image back to a caller via a parcelable on an intent reduces the size to ~50k.

Search for the next text in the below source code link: **Limit to 50k pixels so we can return it in the intent**

Source Code Link: [**Android Stock Camera Source Code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/camera/Camera.java#Camera.createCaptureBitmap%28byte%5B%5D%29)

My question is, why this limit, and what are the real size limits of data I can pass via an intent? I could find forums talking about this, but no real documentation from Google on the limits.

Comment: You are more interested in the maximal Byndle size. I was also not able to find anything specific, but it seems 1MB was most commonly mentioned as speculation. BTW this limit has also good implications - you start thinking of "Why the hell do I need to transfer 5MB in a bundle?" There are alternative better ways

Comment: The problem is that to make my app compatible with other apps, I have to be able to return a bitmap in both possible ways which is via Uri and via a bitmap on the intent. So it does not depend on my app, but on how another app asks me for it. And unfortunatelly I've found some apps which asks it via a parcelable on the intent, which I think is a poor design on their side, but what else can I do. So I guess I will have to shrink my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the binder transaction buffer:

> During a remote procedure call, the arguments and the return value of the call are transferred as `Parcel` objects stored in the Binder transaction buffer. If the arguments or the return value are too large to fit in the transaction buffer, then the call will fail and `TransactionTooLargeException` will be thrown.
>
> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions are of moderate size. [1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

If you exceed the Binder transaction buffer limit, you'll get a `TransactionTooLargeException`.

The limit is supposed to be 1MB but it varies by device from little less than 512KB up to almost a full 1MB.

[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)